# How to escape ':', "," and '()' under javascript array which supports both window and linux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have a javascript array with special characters are getting populated from back-end database. I wanted to escape those characters on the front-end to form query string to get the results properly. my array shown below:

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = "abc,def";
a[1] = "abc:def";
a[2] = "abc(def)";
```

my query string formation as shown below:

```
http://localhost:8080/search/?Ar=AND(OR(category1:abc,def),OR(category2:abc:def),OR(category3:abc(def)));
```

my query string parameter is getting separated by ':" character, but my data itself having ':' characters are failing my query to get the results.
I triend encodeURIComponent() in-built functions, but it fails in linux box.Escape special characters should support both window and linux as well.
Any help on this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's not like there're operating systems that can't read certain characters!

Comment: What do you mean "fails in linux box"? What browser/Javascript engine/whatever are you using? How does it fail?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me...

Comment: a[0] = escape("abc,def");

Comment: `:` shouldn't have any side effects like that at that point in the URL. How are you trying to parse the URL on the server? What does "fails in the linux box mean"? Is Linux running on the client or the server? How does it fail? *Exactly* what URL does the browser's developer tools' net tab show is being requested? Is it really a Linux / Windows issue or do different browsers have different results?

Comment: @KarolS: Fails on the java code to get the result properly, while doing an urlencode.

Comment: I am trying to populate the query string through hidden input value and get the values in javascript and forming an above URL format and sent to back-end for results.

Comment: @Maniram If it fails in the Java code, then we need to see the Java code too, and we need to know what exactly do you want to accomplish: sample inputs and outputs, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure if i understood your problem. but if you want to escape some characters from an array, you can do soemthing like this.

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = "abc,def";
a[1] = "abc:def";
a[2] = "abc(def)";

var excpList = [',',':','(', ')'];

var res = a.map(function(item,index,array){
           return item.split('').filter(function(item,index,array){
             if(excp.indexOf(item) < 0){
               return item;              
             }
           }).join('');
});
```

res --> `["abcdef", "abcdef", "abcdef"]`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rivepojufefi/1/edit)

Comment: :Sorry to say that, I couldn't change the above URL format, thanks for your support.my query string would be [abc,def][abc:def][abc(def)]

Comment: you can escape them like above ? does that help

Comment: yes it is deprectaed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape